# Dimension in the universe

Tags: spacetime, universe, spacetime-dimensions

I was researching on a project ,that is I have to prepare a lecture on 4d.While browseing in youtube I found myself in this question, 1st  and 3rd dimensions have fundemental forces acting on objects present in them while in 4d it doesn't look like that? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern physics says that there are four fundamental forces, all operating in four-dimensional spacetime.

The four forces are gravity, electromagnetism, the strong nuclear force, and the weak nuclear force.

Three of the dimensions of spacetime are the usual spatial dimensions for which we use coordinates like $x$, $y$, and $z$. The fourth dimension of spacetime is time, so it is different from the other three.

Space and time were unified into spacetime by Einstein’s Special Relativity. When you have two events, one here and now, the other there and then, it turns out that how much they are separated in space and how much they are separated in time depends on how fast the observer observing the events is moving! So neither space by itself nor time by itself has an absolute meaning.

Additional spatial dimensions, such as in string theory, are possible but there is currently no experimental evidence for them.

You should be careful about learning physics from YouTube. There is a lot of misinformation available, but also very good lectures by professors who know what they are talking about.

Comment: Thank you Sir .